# Finding volume of the solid bounded by graphs using double integral

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

My answer is wrong and I don’t what made it wrong. 
Given this equations and limits:
$z=x^2, x=0, x=2, y=0, y=4$
It looks like a parabola that has a plan attached to it on its right leg. As I have set up my integral which looks loke this:
$\iint{x^2}dxdy$ and my limits are $x=0, x=2, y=0, y=4$
After doing the fist integral it became like this:
$\int{x^3/3}dy$ Applying the limit of the x values will give me $\frac{8}{3}$ and integrating it with respect to y will give me:
$\frac{8y}{3}$ Applying the limits of y and the answer will be $\frac{32}{3}$ cu. units. Is there anything that I have done wrong?

Comment: All calculations are fine, and the only thing done wrong is LaTeX.  Use `\frac{1}{2}` for $\frac12$.

Comment: Are these the bounds given in the problem or did you derive these? It also looks like there is a bound missing for the $z$ variable, unless it is just supposed to be understood that the solid is bounded below by the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Yes the limits are given in the problem. The problem was: “$z=x^2, x=0, x=2, y=0, y=4$”.

Comment: Then assuming that the lower bound for $z$ should be $z=0$ I agree with @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 that your calculations look fine. Do you know what the answer is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes I forgot to say that it is included in the problem that the lower bound of z is 0.